# Auto increment number using Trigger

Tags: trigger

We have a custom object A__c whose Name field is an auto number field. Now we have a custom field of Number type, say B__c. The requirement is B__c should be populated with Name-number format for example if the name is 100 which is generated as auto number then B__C should be populated as 100-1 and similarly for next record it should be 101-2.

Seems this is not achievable by auto number field rather would go for trigger?

Comment: What happens to B__c if A__c is less than 100?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Saswat you can create a formula field for that as follows:

```
Name +'-'+ text(VALUE(RIGHT(Name, 1) )+1)
```

i hope this would be helpfull....